# MenuBar and ToolBar don't show together on Qt Android

Tags: android, qml, qtquick2, menubar, qt5.5

I want to show both `MenuBar` and `ToolBar` in my `ApplicationWindow` on Android but it doesn't work:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }
    toolBar: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            ToolButton {
                text: "exit";
                onClicked: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }
    statusBar: Label { text: "statusBar" }
}
```

This code just show the ToolBar. If I comment out the `ToolBar` code, I can see the `MenuBar`. I'm using Qt 5.5.1 on Windows (GCC 4.9).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The observed behaviour is somewhat intended. The platform notes about [`ActionBar`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-platformnotes.html#action-bar) are clear about that:

> The Action Bar is a special Android control that provides many key features including various navigation modes, actions, an options menu, a back button, and also displays the application icon and title.
>
> Unlike Qt Widgets, Qt Quick Controls do not use the native action bar on Android. **ToolBar and MenuBar** are offered as a cross-platform replacement. They **are unified to a single "action bar" when assigned to the appropriate ApplicationWindow properties**.

Hence, what you are observing should be the merge behaviour of the two. If you have trouble implementing the approach, please refer to the [gallery example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-gallery-example.html) which provides a clear, simple implementation of the unified action bar discussed above.